# Create DOM elements within a Constructor function, gotchas, bad practice?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm making a media player. At the moment I'm storing everything I need (DOM reference, parameters, etc.) in an object literal attached via an expando property on the media element. Not really ideal.

Anyways, I've been doing a lot of reading on different design patterns (module, singleton, etc.. stuff like [this](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/)) trying to maybe learn something, find something, that's tested and proven... but I haven't come across anything with regard to creating and storing DOM elements privately or adding event listeners within a Constructor.

Maybe it's just common knowledge and I don't know about it? I really don't know. Part of the problem I'm having is the "this" keyword. For instance...

```
function MakeObject () {
   this.elm = document.createElement('tagName');
   this.otherElm = document.createElement('tagName');
}
MakeObject.protoype.doSomething = function () {
   //"this" refers to instance of MakeObject
   this.elm.something = foo;
   this.otherElm.somethingElse = bar;
};
var instance = new MakeObject();
// With an event listener on instance.elm, "this" no longer refers to instance
// For whatever reason I need to avoid bind.
instance.elm.addEventListener('event', instance.doSomething, false); //blah!
```

So, the question(s)...

Is it bad practice to ... *insert question* ... within a Constructor, making them available for any instance of the Constructor?

1. store variables with keyword "var" (especially created DOM elements)?
2. assign event listeners?

I did my best to come up with something... Just don't know if it's "safe" in terms of memory leaks, circular reference, and all the other smorgasbord of pitfalls that comes along with DOM caching.

I'm using a media player for this example but it could very well be anything.

---

```
<video src='awesomevid.ext'></video>
...
var MediaControl = (function () {
    function playToggle (vid, button) {
       if (vid.paused) {
           vid.play();
           button.textContent = 'Pause';
       }
       else {
           vid.pause();
           button.textContent = 'Play';
       }
    }
    function Constructor (vid) {
        var playButton = document.createElement('button');
        this.play = function () {
            playToggle(vid, playButton);
        }
        button.addEventListener('click', this.play, false);
        vid.parentNode.insertBefore(playButton, vid.nextSibling);
    }
    return Constructor;
}());

var control = new MediaControl( document.querySelector('video') );
control.play(); // both control and button can play/pause video
```

Comment: You say "constructor/instance" once in your title, where you say "constructor/instance *function*", even though an instance is not a function. Then you use it a couple more times in your question. What distinction are you trying to make--between somehow holding a value privately within the constructor scope vs. making the value a property on the instance?

Comment: Constructors should be free of side-effects.

Comment: @ torazaburo   Sorry, instance is an object not a function, I edited my question. I forgot to mention "this". Within the scope of the event listener, "this" will reference the eventTarget and not "this" as in the instance of the constructor. Making it difficult to access properties of the instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an object which relates to a DOM element, then sure, one would keep it as a property on the object.

For instance, any MVC system is likely to hold the DOM element as a property on its views. I wouldn't exactly call this "caching", because caching refers to something you could get back with a little computation; it's just "storing".

If by "caching in the constructor" you mean something like

```
function MyConstructor(elt) {
    this.hide = function() { elt.classList.add('hide'); };
}
```

so that `elt` is private, well, this is merely the difference between holding a value privately vs. holding it in a property on the instance:

```
function MyConstructor(elt) {
    this.elt = elt; 
}
MyConstructor.prototype.hide = function() {
    this.elt.classList.add('hide');
};
```

Which approach to choose depends mainly on design factors, either could be considered best practice.

In either case, the `hide` method is essentially delegating from the object to the DOM element. It's a classical delegation pattern, and there's nothing whatsoever wrong with it, in fact, it's nice and clean and easy to understand. The same goes for adding event listeners. If you have an object which encompasses, or wraps, or is connected to, a DOM element, most often in a one-to-one-relationship, where else would you put such functionality?

You asked about holding/caching the DOM element in the object, but there is also the question of how/where to create the DOM element in the first place. In some cases, the DOM element might already be defined in HTML or a template, and the user of the object just needs to pass it to the constructor or some initialization routine. If the DOM element is part of the intrinsic personality of the object, then we might want the object to create it for us. Whether it's best to do that in the constructor itself, or an initializer, is a matter of opinion.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the input! I guess I'm struggling with is whether or not it's OK to create and store elements within a Constructor or add event listeners. I can do it and it will work but does it mean I should? Just because I haven't really seen others do it, does it mean I shouldn't? I feel like there's something obvious I'm missing, as if there's a reason why others don't do it. I've been racking my brain over this.

Comment: Well, when it comes to constructors, the leaner the better, is the general rule. Unless the event behavior is inextricably bound to the identity of the object itself, to the extent that one could not conceive of the object existing without the event behavior in place, the event listeners should be added in some separate method or initialization routine.

Comment: But wouldn't a separate method or init function just be another function call? Why not get it done all in one shot if it's meant to be a self-contained system? Is it a matter of convention, modularity, etc.? I hit up the js chat-room but it took forever for ppes to take me seriously *sigh*

Comment: never mind, I was doing some pref testing and asides from common conventions I understand why nobody really does it the way i outlined... so slow compared to prototypical inheritance,  wow. Would you be Ok with me deleting this question? Otherwise, I'll accept your answer as correct... Thanks again.